# Pricing for google translate api

Tags: google-translate

one of our clients want to use google translate in its web application which is built in asp.net C#. First of all, is its free version or paid version?
I found one reference and we have already tried it.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp

The only concern is can we use without Api key or license or we need to purchase. Our asp.net code will be published in IIS and multiple users are there to access this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a free service.
You can use it without API key or license.
It translates your site on front-end, and totally different from having a page with multiple languages.

Check https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest if you need server side translating and more options.